# footer getting mixed up in content area.

Tags: css, wordpress

My footer is linking the posts on the music page and cannot figure out why it is getting mixed up. I would like separate like the other pages. FYI, I'm using a wordpress plugin, Custom fields, to create the posts on the music page. http://listentotheway.com/music/

music.php :

```
<?php 
/*

 Template Name: Music Page

 */

 get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="music-content">
  <p> This is music.php </p>

   <?php

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'music'  
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"<?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php the_field('description'); ?> <-----This has to do with the plugin.


<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

style.css :

```
/* music page */
#music-content {
display: block;
float: left;
}


/* Footer */

 footer {
 background-color: #eaeaea;
 display: block;
 clear: both;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
 }
```

Comment: i'm assuming it's giving you no errors in developer tools or page source view? b.c normally these things are just a missing div or closing a tag or what not that should show in source view for chrome or firefox

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't getting any errors. However, I should definitely be able to spot errors like this but that will come with more experience. Glad Stackoverflow exists for beginners like me. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just haven't closed the `<a>` link tag in your content, and your links are malformed.

No closing greater than `>` after the `<a href=".."` and no tag close `</a>` following the anchor text.

```
<h3><a href="http://listentotheway.com/music/here-is-another-one/"Here is another one</h3>
YAY

<h3><a href="http://listentotheway.com/music/this-is-a-music-project/"This is a music project</h3>
This is where you find music
```

Should look more like:

```
<h3><a href="http://listentotheway.com/music/here-is-another-one/">Here is another one</a></h3>
YAY

<h3><a href="http://listentotheway.com/music/this-is-a-music-project/">This is a music project</a></h3>
This is where you find music
```

In your PHP:

`<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>`

Comment: thank you very much. I'm still a noob and development so I appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help! We all start somewhere. You were darn close :}

Answer (score 0):

please use this and try again

```
<?php 
/*

 Template Name: Music Page

 */

 get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="music-content">
  <p> This is music.php </p>

   <?php

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'music'  
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h3>
<?php the_field('description'); ?> <-----This has to do with the plugin.


<?php endwhile;?>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```